# Is There any Problems with installing vlc in laptop causing damage for laptop speakers

Tags: software-installation, vlc

Is there any problem with installing vlc in laptops there is a hipe that installing vlc in laptops will cause a severe damage to speakers of laptop

Comment: Can you cite sources for this hype? Otherwise, this is just random speculation and FUD. You should have no problems with installing vlc on a laptop, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this belief is due to [stupid customer support using it as an excuse to make a laptop's warranty void, and charge the customer](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/80989-35-does-media-player-damage-speakers).

You can safely install VLC, it won't harm your speakers. Aside from the fact that VLC developers are not fools, speakers' power output is set in the firmware, and can't be arbitrarily changed to an excessive value by a program so to damage them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be due to the fact that VLC actually allows you to "boost" the volume to 200%, although I don't think anybody actually pushes it to the limit as the quality decreases. Anyway, I think that might be the reason why VLC has been pointed out (same goes to GOM player anyway). I've used t for couple of years now, no problems at all even with warranty issues on my dell, now using it on Lenovo TP, again no issues but I haven't had any contact with the support regarding the warranty.